# Listing table items as String for VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2012

I've been trying to output my results from a table as a String for awhile now. Whenever I use a query in my table and call the Field Table Adapter, it will always show a foreign key constraint exception. I have deleted all my primary and foreign keys to test but it still shows the same exception. I have tried using this code to output to a textbox :

```
Public Sub listfields()

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables.Item("")
    Dim fieldname As String = Field_nameComboBox.SelectedItem
    dt = FieldvalueTableAdapter.GetData
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    While i < dt.Rows.Count
        txtbx_field_list.Text = dt.Rows(i).Item("field_name")
        txtbx_field_list2.Text = dt.Rows(i).Item("field_value")
        txtbx_field_list3.Text = dt.Rows(i).Item("sort_priority")

        i += 1
    End While
End Sub
```

However, this shows the last item in the array only. Is there a way to either use a query to output data I want as a string or a method of placing the results into a string?

Thank you.

Comment: of course it will show only the last one, since you are overriding the data in your `txtbx_field_list` on each looping.

Comment: So does that mean that I should declare an array to store the rows in first then output it on the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to show all you records in one textBox with delimiter |  
use :

```
   Dim i As Integer = 0

While i < dt.Rows.Count - 1
    txtbx_field_list.Text  += " | " & dt.Rows(i).Item("field_name") & " | " & Environment.NewLine
    txtbx_field_list2.Text += " | " & dt.Rows(i).Item("field_value") & " | " & Environment.NewLine
    txtbx_field_list3.Text += " | " & dt.Rows(i).Item("sort_priority") & " | " & Environment.NewLine

    i += 1
End While
```

I still don;t uderstand what you want:

+---------------------+------------------------------+---------------------+
|Name 1 | Name2 | Name 3 | Val 1 Val2 Val3|sort1 sort2 sort3|

or you want 
Name1 | val1 | sort1 |
Name2 | val2 | sort2 | 
 etc..

Comment: Yup! This is what I needed! Thank you! So I'm assuming that If I wanted to output this individually as a string, I would just save them and delimit them?

Comment: yep !  mark the answer pls if you are happy :) have fun ! ;)

Comment: Yep! Is that the green tick? I've done it if it is. 
Just a follow up question, how would I use the query in the tables to load the data? Whenever I try to set a query with a variable, it always says foreign key constraint exception. I have gotten rid of all my primary and foreign keys to test but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: SELECT field_value_id, field_name, sort_priority, field_value FROM fieldvalue where field_name = @field_name. I'm using the SQL Express I think? It's the one attached to visual studio 2012.

Comment: I hope " FROM fieldvalue" is table name ..fieldvalue and read this : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212846%28v=sql.80%29.aspx, in theory the SQL is ok, can you capture generated SQL, or what is in variable, try Console.WriteLine(sql)

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding each of the text Box variables on each loop iteration.

Change the '=' to '+=' to get all items,
add delimiters if necessary.

Comment: I'm a little confused. 
Which = do i change? 
     txtbx_field_list.Text += dt.Rows(i).Item("field_name")? 
Sorry. I'm not very clear on this.

Comment: int i = 0;
        var someTextBoxValue = string.Empty;

        //That's what you are doing : i = "9"
        while (i < 10)
        {
            someTextBoxValue = i.ToString();
            i++;
        }

        i = 0;
        someTextBoxValue = string.Empty;

        //That's what you want : i = "0123456789"
        while (i < 10)
        {
            someTextBoxValue += i;
            i++;
        }

Comment: I have set the textbox to be multiline so I need a way of listing the items in the array. I tried outputting the code to the console with Console.writeline(dt.rows(i).item("field_name")). However, it would repeat all the entries. So instead of the standard 2 outputs which are T1F and T2F, It will say T1F T2F T1F T2F T1F T2F and so on.

Comment: So sorry. I don't really understand your code. 
Do you mean I have to dim a new variable to store the textbox so like : Dim fieldtext As String = txtbx_field_list.Text -- Then declare a loop :
While i  < dt.rows.count (Max number of entries) -- Then place the entries into an array? That seems to be what I'm trying to achieve now.

Comment: What I mean is:
1. When you iterate the rows, you are always assigning the text box variable with the current item in the row index.
This is noticed by the '=' assignment inside the while statement.

2. If you want to create a single string out of all of the rows, you need to change the '=' to '+=' so it will not override the value on each loop iteration, but add the current row index to the existing value.

makes sense?